# Android Page taking too much to load which contains 5 different services in a single page

Tags: android, performance, mobile-application

In my Android application, after login, dashboard page will appears. That page includes different services (more than 5) in a single page. So It will take too much time to load. What is the reason behind that??? Am I missing something Or Android native bahavior is this???

Thanks in advance,

Karthik N

Comment: Some Code and explaining exactly what you expect might help us understand your problem.

Comment: Landing Page contains 5 widgets like Event, Player Performance, Videos, Documents etc., Data for Each widget will comes from different services. So my page takes too much time to load all the data.

Comment: So this is the expected behavior. You can optimize though. You can call your services sequentially, and/or You can show an appropriate loading for each part so it is less painful. 5 services must take time man.

Comment: Thanks for the info... I will rectify that...